# Sequence increasing and non-negative terms.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

We suppose to have an increasing sequence $\{a_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, where $a_n\ge 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=a>0,$$ then for all $\varepsilon>0$ exists $\nu\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\rvert a_n-a\lvert<\varepsilon$ for all $n>\nu$. In particular, results that $$a_n-a>-\varepsilon.$$

> *Question.*
> From what has just been said can we conclude that it exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{n_0}>0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Take $\varepsilon := a/3$ in your definition of convergence: for all $n$ sufficiently large, they must satisfy

$$\begin{align*} 
|a_n - a| < \frac a 3 
\implies& - \frac a 3 < a_n - a \\
\implies& 0<\frac 2 3 a < a_n
\end{align*}$$

then.

Loosely, the limiting value "sucks" everything in to be very close to it and that "sucking in" is inescapable. Since the limit is positive, eventually the sequence must always be positive.